# Bing Azure Search API using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, bing-api

I am learning how to make an AJAX request to the Bing Azure Search API, I've got the account signed up and retrieved a key, but I kept getting errors on the ajax callback.

```
var key = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var searchURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=web&Query=';

$('input').on('keyup', function (evt) {

        getResults($(this).val());

});

function getResults(query) {
    var q = query;
    var url = encodeURI(searchURL + q );

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function(response){
        alert(response);

    });
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search for anything...">
        </div>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Here it is: 
jquery.min.js:4 
GET https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=web&Query=l&callback=jQuery213043548846896737814_1424998394840&_=1424998394841 
jquery.min.js:4 
n.ajaxTransport.send
jquery.min.js:4 
n.extend.ajax
main.js:15 
getResults
main.js:6 
(anonymous function)
jquery.min.js:3 
n.event.dispatch
jquery.min.js:3 
n.event.add.r.handle

Comment: @andrewb just added my html as well. thanks!